# How to resolve curl ssl certificate error?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am trying to issuing a web request to ACS(Microsoft Access Control Service) containing User Id and password and will receive authentication apikey  from ACS.But When I send request it gives below error

> Curl error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate

PHP Code

```
$temp = array('wrap_name'=>$wrap_name,'wrap_password'=>$wrap_password,'wrap_scope'=>$wrap_scope);
$temp = http_build_query($_POST);
$ch = curl_init();    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$baseAdress);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $temp); 

$output = curl_exec ($ch); 
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: You are trying it from local system?

Comment: @PareshGami Yes,I am trying to call it from local system .

Comment: @PeeHaa:Its win 10

Comment: Make the code live on server. it will solve your issue

Comment: @PareshGami: After putting code on server .Its working.Thanks

Comment: @Aanshi you understand why this happen in local?

Comment: @PareshGami: No.Can you explain it?

Comment: whenever you are call some third party web services using curl they check for ssl certificate in install on calling system or not. In our local system ssl is not enable by default. so when you go live server provider have ssl install in server so that is work in live

Comment: @PareshGami:Thanks.Why dont you add it as answer ?

Comment: Thanks. but this question is marked as duplicate so i cannot post answer here. but i can put answer in other question which is noted above

Comment: I post my answer in above question.